# SQL: mysqli_query, no output

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['username'];
$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$db_name");
$sql1="SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE username='$user'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
echo $query;
```

Im not sure what's the problem with this, I've tried searching around here and tried different ways of writing the syntax and checking for errors in parameter but still no output for the command. What am i missing here?

UPDATE

```
$sql1="SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE username='$user'";
$query=mysqli_query($sql1,$con);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$uid=$row[0];
echo $uid;
```

As answered by the others, I tried doing this. There is still no output or an output of 0 was given. Where if I tried the query in sql, it shows the right one.

UPDATE 2

It tried the var_dump() command and it returns NULL. Does that mean it can't read the database?

Comment: where is the code of output or echo?

Comment: Actually you do not any code for display output

Comment: @Sadikhasan oh sorry, forgot to indicate in the post. I did use echo.

Comment: It's required to fetch data once query is executed successfully.

Comment: @RajendraYadav I used echo, updated the post.

Comment: @Rikesh so mysqli_query does not have an output that i could echo?

Comment: You get any error? Maybe your MySQL Connection failed?

Comment: @Yannici There were no errors, and I'm using the standard "if (mysqli_connect_errno())" to check if there are errors.

Comment: I don't know why it should be better, but you can try: `SELECT \`UserID\` FROM \`User\` WHERE \`username\` = '$user'` Also check, if the tablename and fieldnames are correct!

Comment: @Yannici I tried it as well, but still the same. Does the var_dump resulting to NULL mean something?

Comment: if var_dump outputs null it means there is no data in the given variable or the variable is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do some workaround with my problem using mysql syntax. Still not able to determine the problem with mysqli but able to finished my task. Thanks for answering guys.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` gives no output. A successfully query returns a resource. You have to handle the resource with `mysqli_fetch_object`, `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Also you gave `$con` parameter **before** `$sql1` which is wrong. You have to put the connection first, then the query variable.

Example:

```
<?php

session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");
$sql1 = "SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE username='$user'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

var_dump($fetch);

?>
```

Comment: Please see my updated post, I tried what you said but still no output was given.

Answer (score 0):

`$query` will be a "Resource". You can use for example `$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);` and then `echo $result[0];`May there's another way, but that's a simple one!

Comment: i tried using that, but still there's no output. Is there a mistake with my query?

Comment: Try echoing your query and see if it's printing what you want. May the variable inside the simplequotes are doing something. Take a try.

Comment: This is what I got from echoing it SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE username='1234'

Is there a mistake in the query?

Comment: Query seems to be OK, if the filed UserID is exactly typed like that and the table is User (all beign case sensitive)

Comment: I typed them all correctly, what would it mean if var_dump() gets null?

Comment: Try commenting all, and uncomment line per line for make sure you don't get an error. Try using var_dump for that.